# How can I perform multiple operations in a single applyEdits?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-android

I want to perform update and delete operation in a single applyEdits() call from my android application, my code is as below:

```
Thread.sleep(300);
layer.applyEdits(null, deletes, updates, new CallbackListener<FeatureEditResult[][]>() {
...
});
```

I am able to perform the desired operation only before applying a certain sleep interval, if not, the deletes array gets passed as empty, and therefore, the delete and update operations does not take place in a single transaction.

Please provide your inputs.

Comment: Cross-posted as http://stackoverflow.com/q/43522614/820534

Comment: I don't understand why there is a downvote on a valid question? Would the voter mind to explain it, please?

Comment: Cross-posts have a tendency to attract downvotes.  Please do not cross-post.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/215590

Comment: @PolyGeo Downvoting at SO seems okay as it is less relevant there, I agree. But why downvoting here at GIS?

Comment: I know that I have never removed a downvote when asked about it. That may or may not be the same for a downvoter on this cross-post. The paramount thing with voting on SE is that it is anonymous.

Comment: @PolyGeo Well, I don't mind getting downvoted for a non-relevant question, but if there is a downvote on something logical, I would definitely need a reason for it.

Answer (score 2):

What if you call `deleteFeaturesAsync()` and then `updateFeaturesAsync()` when you get the callback?  Does it have to be in the same operation?  Two asynchronous calls may work better.

I'm a little rusty on Android/Java, but maybe something like (I cannot test right now):

```
public ListenableFuture<Feature>deletesFuture = layer.deleteFeaturesAsync(deletes);

// add done listener
deletesFuture.addDoneListener(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    try {
     // now try doing the updates
     public LisenableFuture<Feature>updatesFuture = layer.updateFeaturesAsync(updates) // updates is a global var

     // add yet another event listener on the update features if you want
     updatesFuture.addDoneListener(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
        try {
         // do stuff when updates have been added
        } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), "updating features failed: " + e.getMessage());
        }
       }
      }
     } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), "deleting features failed: " + e.getMessage());
     }
    }
   }
```

If you haven't done so already, you should check out the [ArcGIS Runtime Samples for Android on GitHub](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but performing two different operations is not what I need to do. Because if somehow, the delete call succeeds and the update call fails, then I am down with data loss which is unacceptable. :( The whole idea is to perform applyEdits in a single transaction.

Comment: Moreover, the samples that I read tells about either 'adds' or 'deletes' or 'updates'. None of them talks about performing these operations in one go.

Comment: What if you just send a POST request to the ArcGIS REST API?  Just convert the features to JSON and make the call manually?  It will not return back features, but at least you can do them all in the same [applyEdits](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Apply_Edits_Feature_Service_Layer/02r3000000r6000000/) call.  From what I saw, the Android SDK doesn't support an `applyEdits` method.

Comment: That's the last option I kept with me; using ArcGIS REST API directly. However, can you please explain with references, your statement : "Android SDK doesn't support an applyEdits method." ?

Comment: The only documentation I can provide is the [FeatureTable](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/data/FeatureTable.html) API Reference. I have not actually used the Quartz release (100.0) of the SDK, I have only used the 10.2.7 release for Android and I do not remember seeing an `applyEdits` there either.  Both versions only have separate add, update, and delete methods.  The iOS SDK is the same way.

Comment: What about [ArcGISFeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/10-2/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/ags/ArcGISFeatureLayer.html)? It has _applyEdits_ method under _Public Methods_ section.

Comment: I would say try that if you are using version 10.2.9 and you have just answered your own question.  However, you're still going to have an issue with data loss if doing them all in one shot (I think?).  If using the 100.0 version, I haven't found the `ArcGISFeatureLayer` class (maybe deprecated?), but I did see you can get at features that have been added, deleted, or updated from the [ArcGISFeatureTable](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/data/ArcGISFeatureTable.html) class in case the updates or deletes failed.

Comment: If using version 100.0, I still think that breaking out the update and delete into separate calls would be best if you're concerned about data loss. The runtime SDK's do editing through the REST API when using services, so the [applyEdits](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Apply_Edits_Feature_Service_Layer/02r3000000r6000000/) can have the deletes work and updates fail, at least if you break them out into separate operations you can handle accordingly if one fails and recover features by either `getDeletedFeaturesAsync` or `getUpdatedFeaturesAsync` from `ArcGISFeatureTable`

Comment: I strongly believe that breaking out things into separate calls (update and delete) is far more risky for my application. The operation which I want to perform is a 1-1 or 0-0 situation, either both updates and deletes should execute successfully, or both should fail. Performing any one of the operation successfully will lead to data inconsistency for my application. And I am using _applyEdits_ from version 10.2.9 itself, but it requires some time delay (variable over Wi-Fi, 3G, 2G, etc.) before calling it, which is my actual problem, can you please go through my original question again?